# $\mathbb Z_2$-equivariant cohomology of tori

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences, equivariant-cohomology

I consider the tori $X=(\mathbb R/ 2 \pi \mathbb Z)^d$ on which the group $\mathbb Z_2$ acts by $x \mapsto -x$ for the nontrivial element of $\mathbb Z_2$. This action has $2^d$ fixed points, which are of the form $x=(x_1,...,x_d)$ with each $x_i$ equal to $0$ or $\pi$. I would like to know what are the equivariant cohomology groups $H^{\bullet}_{\mathbb Z_2}(X, \mathbb Z)$ (although I suspect $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients might be easier and would be happy to learn about these cohomology groups as well). I know that there is a spectral sequence with $E_2^{p,q}=(\mathbb{RP}^{\infty},H^q(X,\mathbb Z))$, but it is unclear to me how to extract useful information from that.

Answer (score 2):

Since in the fibration $X \hookrightarrow X \times_\mathbb{Z_2}E{\mathbb{Z}_2} \to B\mathbb{Z}_2 \simeq \mathbb{RP}^{\infty}$ the fiber's cohomology groups are freely generated, your situation calls for the [Leray–Hirsch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leray%E2%80%93Hirsch_theorem) (in Hatcher it is p. 432). You want then the inclusion $X \hookrightarrow X \times_\mathbb{Z_2}E{\mathbb{Z}_2}$ to induce a surjection on cohomologies. For that, it is enough to show the surjectivity of $H_\mathbb{Z_2}^1(X) \to H^1(X)$ (use multiplicativity). I can't now think of a clever way to show that but to investigate 1- and 2-dimensional cells seems to be enough. (Another way which might work is to replace absolute circles with pairs of intervals and their boundaries: in the relative case you won't have the first row in the spectral sequence, so the differential $d_2^{0,1}$ would vanish, which is equivalent to surjectivity.)

*UPD*: The spectral sequence reference was unnecessary, deleted.

Comment: I figured out that what is needed for Leray-Hirsch does not hold over $\mathbb Z$, because I know it is false over $\mathbb R$. In the case of real coefficients the calculation can be done using differential forms using the Cartan model and it turns out that equivariant cohomology of $S^1$ coincides with the ordinary one in even degrees but it is trivial in odd degrees. It might be true that assumptions of Leray-Hirsch are satisfied over $\mathbb Z_2$, but I have not been able to verify that yet.

Comment: @Blazej I've tried again for $\Bbb{Z}$ and indeed got a trivial map instead of surjective. Sorry if my answer led you astray.
So, for a circle the answer is trivial? I'm confused by the way you put it.

Comment: Did you find it to be trivial in all degrees? My result (over $\mathbb R$) was that surjectivity holds for cohomology in even degrees, but in odd degrees restricition map is trivial. I could have made an error, of course. If the restriction map was trivial over $\mathbb Z$, I think it would also be trivial over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Blazej I only checked the $H^1$.

Comment: @Blazej $H^*(S^1)$ is zero when $* > 1$, that's why it is strange to me that you speak about even and odd degrees.

Comment: I see my mistake. I have written $S^1$ in the above comment, but I meant $(S^1)^d$, which has nonzero cohomologies up to degree $d$.